# the "%" character in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell, and I saw this code snippet recently:

```
$users = Get-User 
$users | % { $user = $_; Get-MailboxStatistics $_ | % 
    { 
        "User name:{0} - some mailbox statistics: {1}" -f $user.SomePropertyOfUser, $_.SomePropertyOfMailbox
    } 
}
```

What does the % mean here? It seems to be marking the beginning of a block of code, is that right?
many thx!

Comment: try `get-help %` in powershell console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an alias for the `foreach-object` cmdlet

another other alias frequently use is : `?` that stands for `where-object`